# continuous mapping of metrizable space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $f$ be a continuous  mapping of a metrizable  space $(X,\tau)$  onto a topological space  $(Y,\tau_1)$ .  Is $(Y,\tau_1)$  necessarily metrizable ?

Comment: This is answered in (or implied by) lots of other posts here. See the first comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1129897/a-nonmetrizable-image-of-a-metrizable-space), answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388485/is-the-continuous-image-of-a-compact-metric-space-second-countable) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190303/a-condition-for-the-image-of-a-metrizable-space-to-be-metrizable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be any infinite metrisable space. Let $Y$ be the same set in the cofinite topology, and let $f$ be the identity function $f(x)=x$. $f$ is continuous as $F \subseteq Y$ is closed iff $F$ is finite or $F=Y$ and in both cases $f^{-1}[F](= F)$  is closed in $X$; it's either $X$ or it's finite and in metric spaces, finite sets are always closed.

Then $Y$ is not metrisable, as it’s not even Hausdorff. But $f$ shows that it is the continuous image of $X$.